# setOnItemClickListener Not launching Activity in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I am following this tutorial to Implement Navigation Drawer.
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

I am able to set the title in the ActionBar but it is **not launching the activity.**

I have reffered to:- [setOnItemClickListener() in navigation drawer not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271249/setonitemclicklistener-in-navigation-drawer-not-working)
, [Navigation Drawer setOnItemClickListener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022049/navigation-drawer-setonitemclicklistener-not-working) and many other links.

This is my xml where navigation drawer is and it is also my `activity_main`.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LL1">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/LL1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/LL2">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/Amount"
            android:hint="Enter your Budget" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/LLR3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LL2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/LL3">

            <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:text="More Talktime less Validity"
                android:id="@+id/Calculate"
                fbutton:buttonColor="@color/fbutton_color_peter_river"
                fbutton:shadowColor="@color/fbutton_color_belize_hole"
                fbutton:shadowEnabled="true"
                fbutton:shadowHeight="5dp"
                fbutton:cornerRadius="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="More Validity less talktime"
                android:id="@+id/Calculate2"
                fbutton:buttonColor="@color/fbutton_color_pumpkin"
                fbutton:shadowColor="@color/fbutton_color_pomegranate"
                fbutton:shadowEnabled="true"
                fbutton:shadowHeight="5dp"
                fbutton:cornerRadius="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Calculate"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Calculate" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/connect"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LLR3">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/res"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LLR3" />
        <com.top.up.planner.MyTextViewNormal
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
            android:id="@+id/res"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <com.top.up.planner.MyTextViewNormal
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/connect"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My java code:-

```
         private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter Navadapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();
        mDrawerList.bringToFront();
        mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        Navadapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(Navadapter);


        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.mipmap.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

public class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {

            case R.id.item1:
                OnShare();
                return true;
            case R.id.item2:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Help.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

And the drawble is being set to a Back arrow, but i have coded it show hamburger icon how to fix that ?

Comment: This tutorial is out dated and not using the latest libraries. Always check the date of these articles and if it isn't 2015 or later ignore them. It is also good practice to only have two views within DrawerLayout, your FrameLayout and what ever is in the drawer. You should only use the activity that has the drawer as a controller for fragments that you inflate within the FrameLayout.

Comment: sure, I will keep in mind that :-)

Comment: Along with Eugene (to clarify) when you mention "not launching the activity" its not launching any Activity. The tutorial is setup for Fragments (which frags are what works best with the swipe menu). So you need to change it or your code accordingly or it will fail to work. I'm not helping to fix this. IMO you should start a new app with a generated swipe menu (Android Studio has this and I believe Eclipse did as well) and copy/paste that or just move everything over and then find the method you can use to start whatever you want instead of copy/paste some web tutorial code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to onCreate :
mDrawerToggle.syncState();

Comment: Weird, it doesn't even let me use that ActionBarDrawerToggle constructor. I'm using constructor with toolbar. I used similar code to this and it works fine: http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html